# Why can't I update IdentityUser with Attach()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

The code bellow throws:

> Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0
> row(s).

```
var updatedUser = new User { Id = _currentUserService.UserId, MyBool = true };
_dbContext.Users.Attach(updatedUser);
_dbContext.Entry(updatedUser).Property(user => user.MyBool).IsModified = true;
await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync()
```

User is inherited from `IdentityUser` and this is the only one place in my project, where such updating approach is not working. I'm doing this without `UserManager`, as I don't want to fetch all user columns. All I want is just to update `MyBool` property. So I don't need other ways to do it, I simply want to understand why I get this behavior.

Sure thing I'm passing not the same bool.
I assume that I don't get how `IdentityUser` affects on `DbContext`, as the code above works for all my custom entities which are not connected with `Identity`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: I forgot to add await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync() in my question, my fault. If I didn't write it in my project, I wouldn't get Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s) exception. The question is stil relevant..

Comment: If you want to execute an `UPDATE SET MyBool=1 Where ID=@id` do that. Don't try to approximate it through the ORM. All ORMs are built to deal with object graphs, not as replacements for SQL. To update an object with an ORM you have to load the object, modify it and then persist it. Yes, that's slow, requires two round trips and is far more likely to lead to concurrency conflicts.

Comment: Yeah, I've already been told that I should fetch the whole entity no matter how many columns I will update. Yes, and as you mentioned I was afraid of performance speed. It looks like I'm trying to combine best from both SQL and ORM and ruining ORM concept a bit.

Answer (score 2):

In the base class for `IdentityDbContext<TUser>` you can find the following inside OnModelCreating():

```
b.Property(u => u.ConcurrencyStamp).IsConcurrencyToken();
```

So your `var updatedUser = new User { }` approach will not work.

You need to fetch the user first. In normal code that should always be the case anyway, you don't want to lose the Name and everything else in an 'update', do you?

Comment: It's a perfectly fine method to just modify one property without overwriting any other properties. But you correctly indicate that they should also set the `ConcurrencyStamp` property which does require a roundtrip to the database.

Comment: Yes, I know. I misread that line with IsModified. When you do the roundtrip you  might just as well leave that to the ChangeTracker.

Comment: Oh, thanks for your answer, I'll take a look a bit later.

Answer (score 0):

I always use the code like this:

```
var existedUser = _dbContext.Set<ApplicationUser>()
                            .FirstOrDefault( i=> i.UserId=_currentUserService.UserId);

if(existedUser ==null) ... error

existedUser.MyBool=true;
_dbContext.Entry(existedUser).Property(user => user.MyBool).IsModified = true;
await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: *I don't want to fetch all user columns.* That's the point of the question. See the other answer: it requires that the current value of `ConcurrencyStamp` be retrieved from the database. Whether not fetching the entire record is nothing but premature optimization is another discussion.